# Galaxy s2 4.4 totaly stock rom?

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, 4.4-kitkat, rom

I am looking for 4.4.x rom for my galaxy s2. I have installed beanstalk 4.4.2 rom, but what I don't like about it is that it is very "custom". I am looking for rom, similar to super nexus - absolutely stock google android experience. Can anyone recommend something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/)? It is not *absolutely stock **Google Android** experience* but *absolutely stock **AOSP** (Android Open Source Project) experience*. It means that all Google proprietary additions are not included (for legal reasons), but you can install them easily using a package called **gApps**. In the end you have something very close to a Nexus experience plus very little additions that are all useful.

Comment: Great tip. However, it is only in snapshot M4 stage, so it is very buggy.

Comment: actually, I've been using CyanogenMod on an SGS 2 for almost 4 months now and it's really stable.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what you should opt for , you should go for AOSP based ROMs ;
here's a list :

1.CyanogenMod (minimal but necessary cutomization)

2.Paranoid Android (same as Cyanogenmod very less cutomization)

3.OmniRom ( basically same )

4.PAC (mixture of Paranoid android , Cyanogenmod and AOKP) ( a bit more of cutomization)

You should first checkout the official websites of these ROMs , or you can head to XDA forums and find official and unofficial build of these or even more ROMs , but according to your preference look for "[AOSP]" in threads .

Link : http://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s2#romList